# multiple errors trying to run "Hello, world!" desktop application QT

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to get started with QT. Specifically, the "Hello, world!" desktop application in this basic tutorial: [Getting Started on the Commandline](https://wiki.qt.io/Getting_Started_on_the_Commandline)

The .cpp file is called helloX.cpp with the following contents:

```
#include <QtGui>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
 QApplication app(argc, argv);
 QLabel label("Hello, world!");
 label.show();
 return app.exec();
}
```

here are a multitude of errors that I get when I run make and I can't find any reference to these errors anywhere! any help troubleshooting would be greatly appreciated.

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -c -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -O2 -std=gnu++11 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -Wall -W -fPIC -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -I. -I/Users/hassanshallal/anaconda/include/qt -I/Users/hassanshallal/anaconda/include/qt/QtGui -I/Users/hassanshallal/anaconda/include/qt/QtCore -I. -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Headers -I/Users/hassanshallal/anaconda/mkspecs/macx-clang -o helloX.o helloX.cpp
helloX.cpp:4:15: error: variable has incomplete type 'QApplication'
 QApplication app(argc, argv);
              ^
/Users/hassanshallal/anaconda/include/qt/QtCore/qobject.h:452:18: note: forward declaration of
      'QApplication'
    friend class QApplication;
                 ^
helloX.cpp:5:2: error: use of undeclared identifier 'QLabel'; did you mean 'QAccessible::Label'?
 QLabel label("Hello, world!");
 ^~~~~~
 QAccessible::Label
/Users/hassanshallal/anaconda/include/qt/QtGui/qaccessible.h:360:9: note: 'QAccessible::Label' declared
      here
        Label         = 0x00000001,
        ^
helloX.cpp:5:8: error: expected ';' after expression
 QLabel label("Hello, world!");
       ^
       ;
helloX.cpp:5:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'label'
 QLabel label("Hello, world!");
        ^
helloX.cpp:6:2: error: use of undeclared identifier 'label'
 label.show();
 ^
helloX.cpp:5:2: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
 QLabel label("Hello, world!");
 ^~~~~~
1 warning and 5 errors generated.
make: *** [helloX.o] Error 1
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: show your code.

Comment: did you forget a `#include`?

Comment: _Seems_ to be missing qt libraries

Comment: I included QtGui which comes with QApplication and QLabel!

Comment: What is in your `.pro` file?

Comment: Not quite sure what .pro file is?

Comment: You should have created one following that tutorial. `.pro` is the extension. Typing `qmake -project` will create  one, then edit it as directed in the tutorial.

Comment: @mansanto, as you are new with Qt, you better stick to Qt documentations at the beginning , there are full and rich examples you can choose to download with Qt .. follow instructions how to install Qt and the examples, on MAC OS from here: https://www.qt.io/download-qt-installer?hsCtaTracking=9f6a2170-a938-42df-a8e2-a9f0b1d6cdce%7C6cb0de4f-9bb5-4778-ab02-bfb62735f3e5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. qmake should be in your path. In the terminal do `export PATH=<path to qmake exe>;$PATH`
2. You need to correctly set the .pro file like stated in the tutorial.

   2a. With `INCLUDE+=` add the correct include path for qt headers

   2b. with `Qt+=` add the libraries you're gonna use. For your simple example **gui** and **widget** should be fine.
3. Go to your project root and run **qmake** and **make** like stated in the tutorial you are referencing.
4. Don't forget to include the headers for every widget you use in your app like QApplication, QLabel, etc.

Comment: Hi StPiere, thanks for the stepwise answer: 1) qmake -v on the terminal evaluates to: QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.6.2 in /Users/hassanshallal/anaconda/lib indicating that qmake is in my path. I run qmake with no problem. 2) qmake -project and qmake run with no issue, the output above is when I run make afterwards.

Comment: do #include <QApplication> and #include <QLabel> at the top of your cpp file

Comment: I just did this, ran qmake -project, qmake, and make. Other issues showed up: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "QApplication::exec()", 
  "QApplication::QApplication(int&, char**, int)", 
  "QApplication::~QApplication()", 
  "QLabel::QLabel(QString const&, QWidget*, QFlags<Qt::WindowType>)", 
  "QLabel::~QLabel()", 
  "QWidget::show()", referenced from :_main in helloX.o
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [helloX.app/Contents/MacOS/helloX] Error 1

Comment: try to compile on 32 bit mode. get qt creator, open some sample project and look its configuration.

Comment: Thanks StPiere, it turned out I needed to add QT += widgets to the .pro file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that you have the correct include files for your Qt application and that your build environment can see and link to all of the Qt libraries.  These errors are because your compiler cannot find the Qt APIs you're using.

Answer (score 1):

thanks a lot for the feedback. It turned out all I need is the following:

```
1) add #include <QApplication> to the .cpp file
2) add #include <QLabel> to the .cpp file
3) add: QT += widgets to the .pro file
```

And this took care of all the issues.

Best,